# Deleting any digit yields a prime... is there a name for this?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

My son likes his grilled cheese sandwich cut into various numbers, the number depends on his mood.  His mother won't indulge his requests, but I often will.  Here is the day he wanted 100:

[image: 100 sandwich]

But today he wanted the prime 719, which I obliged.  When deciding which digit to eat first, he went through the choices, trying to make a composite with the digits left behind.  But he quickly realized that eating any digit would leave a prime: 71, 79, 19 are all prime.  Pleased with his discovery of this prime 719, he tried to find a larger one, but couldn't.

My questions:

- Do these primes have a name?
- Can you think of any more of them (clearly 23 is the smallest)?
- Are there an infinite number of them?
- Is there likely to be a way to find them short of using a computer?

Comment: There is a list at http://oeis.org/A034302 and 79 of them  (a prime number!) available at http://oeis.org/A034302/b034302.txt, but no references.

Comment: Here's the same thing with zeros allowed: http://oeis.org/A051362, and 100 of them (a number that remains non-prime if you delete any digit) available at http://oeis.org/A051362/b051362.txt, and a comment 'These might be called "super-prime numbers"', and email addresses of the author of the comment and the author of the entry. However, Wikipedia uses that name for something else: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-prime

Comment: I see no reason to exclude 0 as a digit... seems rather artificial: there are infinitely-many primes with a 0 digit in their decimal expansion (101 is the first, then cf Dirichlet).

Comment: 22 is the smallest. Or do you have an extra rule which says you can't use a digit twice? If that is a rule, there are no infinite numbers, because there are only 9 digits.

Comment: If you truncate the leftmost digit of a prime, and your new truncated number is prime, these are sometimes called left-truncated primes.  Analogously one can discuss right-truncated primes.  Primes which are both left and right truncatable are called two-sided primes.  In view of this, I think the name "truncatable prime" is suitable here.

Comment: @Martijn It seems that the OP requires the original digit to itself be prime.

Comment: @Martijn I intended that the original number be prime as well; edited to clarify this.

Comment: Your son eats primes?  I'm not sure I fully understood what a prime was at his age.  Toast came in soldiers.

Comment: Here is useful information on truncated primes as DJC jas stated: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatablePrime.html

Comment: @Fixee: I think that this can be interesting to you: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31766246/Libros/Matem%C3%A1ticas/Art%C3%ADculos%20y%20Revistas/Minimal%20Primes.ps 

Is a paper, I don't remember where I find it.

Comment: TYou're a pretty awesome parent.  And I suppose the fastest way by hand to generate them would be to start wiht a prime and insert other primes.

Comment: @joriki, [Here is](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31766246/Libros/Matem%C3%A1ticas/Art%C3%ADculos%20y%20revistas/Minimal%20Primes.ps) as promised.

Comment: @leo: Thanks, that's a nice paper :-)

Comment: @joriki, you're welcome

Comment: It's called the Optimus Prime.

Comment: Very nice question, and very nice answers. Nevertheless, it is being assumed that the numbers have to be represented in decimal positional notation, which is obviously not mandatory. I wonder what would happen in other bases, or even in other representations. Has anyone checked that?

Comment: "My son" plus "his mother won't..., but I often will" sounds contradicting.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here is a heuristic for why we should expect there are only finitely many of these numbers.  Let $P$ be the set of positive integers with your special property.

A large number $n$ is prime with probability approximately
$$ \frac{1}{\log n}. $$
For a number $n$ to be in $P$, it must remain prime with the removal of each digit.  Removing a digit from a number $n$ results in a number on the order of 
$$\frac{n}{10}.$$
A number $n$ has approximately
$$\frac{\log n}{\log 10}$$
digits.
As a result, the probability that $n$ is in $P$ can be approximated as
$$ \left( \frac{1}{\log \frac{n}{10} } \right)^{\frac{\log n}{\log 10}} = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{\log \log (n/10)}{\log 10}}}$$
In general, if the probability of $n$ being in a set $S$ is $p(n)$ then if 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p(n)$$
is finite, we can expect $S$ to be finite; if the sum is infinite, we can expect $S$ to be infinite.  In the case of $P$, since the sum
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{\log \log (n/10)}{\log 10}}}$$
converges (by comparison with, say, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$) we may conclude that we should expect $P$ to be finite.

Unfortunately, this is just a heuristic, so does not constitute a proof of the finiteness of $P$, nor does it give any idea how large the largest element of $P$ might be.

Addition: I just realized that I wasn't assuming $n$ needed to be prime to be in $P$, only that it was prime after the removal of any one digit.  So, my $P$ would include 27.  Requiring only prime numbers in $P$ just makes the set smaller, so the above argument applies just as well is we require $P$ to only contain prime numbers.

Comment: Here is heuristic evidence that there are infinitely many of these numbers: let $c(n)$ be the number of integers in $P$ with $n$ decimal digits.  A quick computer program shows $c(2)=4$, $c(3)=11$, $c(4)=14$, $c(5)=16$, $c(6)=18$, $c(7)=13$, $c(8)=14$, $c(9)=18$; therefore $P$ is infinite.  I'm joking, of course, but I would find it remarkable if such a list ended, in spite of your nice argument above.

Comment: By the way, these number don't look random at all: they are heavily biased toward integers with repeated consecutive digits.  Take 711110111, for example: such numbers appear often in our list because if deleting one 1 in a group yields a prime, then obviously deleting any other 1 in that group does as well.

Comment: Good point about the repeated digit thing, Fixee.  I'll have to think about that.

Answer (score 133):

Thanks to everyone for the interesting answers. Here's an improved heuristic that makes use of various parts of them -- the basic approach from Matthew, Fixee's observation of the repeated digits, and Numth' observations about restrictions on the digits. It's still a bit off, but I think it may be further improved taking into account Numth' observation 2; I've only taken into account  observation 1 (mod $2$ and $5$) so far; I think the mod $3$ part will need to be a bit more subtle; more on that later.

Consider numbers with $m$ digits consisting of $k$ strings of repeated digits. For instance, $38800999$ would have $m=8$ and $k=4$. The number of such numbers is $9^k\left(m-1\atop k-1\right)$: We have $9$ choices for the first repeated digit (we can't use $0$) and $9$ choices for the remaining ones (we can't use the previous one), and there are $\left(m-1 \atop k-1\right)$ different way to divide the repetitions. To check that this is right, we can calculate the total number of numbers with $m$ digits:

$$\sum_{k=1}^m 9^k\left({m-1 \atop k-1}\right)=9\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} 9^k\left({m-1 \atop k}\right)=9(1+9)^{m-1}=9\cdot10^{m-1}\;,$$

which is correct.

Like Matthew, I'll use $1/\log x$ as the "probability" of a number to be prime. This isn't quite right, since this is the total density below $x$, whereas we need the marginal density, $(x/\log x)'=1/\log x - 1/\log^2 x$. I'll do the analytic calculations using just $1/\log x$, which gives an upper bound and is thus good enough to show that the sum converges, but I'll give some numerical results using the more precise formula in the end.

So the probability of one of these numbers being prime is $1/\log x$, which we can bound from above by $1/\log 10^m=1/(m\log 10)$. Now we need the probability that the $k$ different numbers that we can get by deleting one of the digits are also prime. Note that for all but the last digit, the deletion doesn't change the last digit.

One of the main reasons why Matthew's heuristic significantly underestimates the abundance of these numbers is that we need to include a factor of $5/2$ for each digit except the last: For each of these digits, given that the original number is prime and the modified number has the same last digit, we already know it isn't divisible by $2$ or $5$, which raises its chances of being prime by a factor of $10/|\{1,3,7,9\}|=5/2$.

So multiplying all these probabilities, we have one factor of $1/(m\log 10)$ for the original number to be prime, $k$ factors of $1/(m\log 10)$ for all the modified numbers to be prime, and $k-1$ factors of $5/2$ to account for the last digit. (We could bound the probability for the modified numbers by $1/((m-1)\log 10)$, but I want to keep things simple first to derive the convergence; I'll get back to that in the numerical estimates).

Now we have all we need to write an upper bound for the sum of the "probabilities" over all numbers:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&
\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{m}9^k\left({m-1 \atop k-1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{m\log10}\right)^{k+1}\left(\frac{10}{4}\right)^{k-1}
\\
&=&
\frac{9}{\log^2 10}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left({m-1 \atop k}\right)\left(\frac{45}{2m\log10}\right)^k
\\
&=&
\frac{9}{\log^2 10}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2}\left(1+\frac{45}{2m\log10}\right)^{m-1}
\\
&<&
\frac{9}{\log^2 10}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2}\mathrm{e}^{45/(2\log10)}
\\
&=&
\frac{9}{\log^2 10}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\right)\mathrm{e}^{45/(2\log10)}
\\
&\approx&
19191
\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Although this is quite a lot bigger than Matthew's result, it's still finite.

The bound is not very tight, for three reasons: I didn't use the fact that the modified numbers have one fewer digit; I dropped the $1/\log^2x$ term; and the exponential bound isn't tight for small $m$. To get a better estimate, let's keep the $1/\log^2x$ term and the power instead of the exponential, and let's roughly estimate the probabilities of the original and modified numbers being prime by using $1/((m-1)\log10)$ for all of them -- that overestimates the probability for the original number and underestimates it for the modified numbers, so should give a better estimate. Putting this all together yields the following estimate for the number of $m$-digit numbers, Fixee's $c(m)$, with $j:=m-1$:

$$9\left(\frac{1}{j\log10}-\frac{1}{(j\log 10)^2}\right)^2\left(1+\frac{45}{2}\left(\frac{1}{j\log10}-\frac{1}{(j\log 10)^2}\right)\right)^j\;.$$

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%289%2a%281/%28j%2alog%2810%29%29-1/%28j%2alog%2810%29%29%5E2%29%5E2%2a%281%2b%2845/2%29%2a%281/%28j%2alog%2810%29%29-1/%28j%2alog%2810%29%29%5E2%29%29%5Ej%29%20for%20j%20=%201%20to%2050)'s a plot. The numbers are reasonably close to the actual ones, but still too low, even at $m=9$, i.e. $j=8$, where the approximations should be reasonable and the maximum is almost attained, but the value is around 11 whereas the actual values are all around 16.

P.S.: I think I figured out how to correctly take into account the restrictions mod $3$; I'll be posting that later in the day.

P.P.S.: I just realized that part of the remaining underestimation stems from the fact that the last digit should also get a factor of $5/2$ if it's repeated. I think that together with the mod $3$ part might get the result roughly in line with the actual numbers.

[**Update:**]

I've produced some more numerical data and improved the estimate as described, and the two are now in quite satisfactory agreement.

For taking into account the restrictions mod $2$, $3$ and $5$, the general approach is to take the original number as given, with the generic probability of being prime, and then to analyze the modified numbers under the condition that the original number is prime. We need to distinguish two cases depending on whether the last digit is repeated. The repeated case is easier to analyze, so I'll treat that first.

So assume that the last digit is repeated. That excludes one place at which to divide the repetitions, so there are $9^k\left(m-2 \atop k-1\right)$ such numbers. In this case, each digit, including the last one, gets a factor of $5/2$ to account for the fact that the corresponding modified number is not divisible by $2$ or $5$. To help in getting the more complicated case of a non-repeated last digit right, it's worthwhile stating more explicitly how this factor of $5/2$ arises from a conditional probability. We can consider the probabilities that a number is coprime to all primes in a set $S$ and that it is coprime to all primes not in $S$ as independent, so that the probability of the number being prime is the product of these two probabilities. Then the probability of a number being coprime to $2$ and $5$ is $\lvert\{1,3,7,9\}/10\rvert=2/5$, and the probability of the number being prime is $p=2/5q$, where $q$ is the probability of it being coprime to all primes other than $2$ and $5$. If we estimate $p$ using the overall density of primes but we know that the number is coprime to $2$ or $5$, then the conditional probability of it being prime is $q=(5/2)p$. This is relatively obvious in the present case, but this way of looking at it will be helpful in dealing with the case of a non-repeated last digit.

Now let's look at the mod $3$ restrictions. The last digit is known to be $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$. If we delete a $3$ or a $9$, the number will still not be divisible by $3$. If we delete a $1$ or a $7$, there is a 50% chance of the number becoming divisible by $3$. Thus, the conditional probability of the modified number being coprime to $3$ is $3/4$, and this has to be divided by the unconditional probability of it being coprime to $3$, which is $2/3$, to obtain the factor $(3/4)/(2/3)=9/8$ by which we need to multiply the unconditional probability estimate.

Now consider the remaining digits, starting from the end. Each digit is different from the one after it, and the one after it is known to be one of the $7$ digits allowed mod $3$. That leaves $6$ allowed digits and $3$ forbidden ones, for a conditional probability of $2/3$. This is equal to the unconditional probability, so we don't need to include any factors to account for the mod $3$ restrictions on the remaining digits.

That completes the considerations for the case of a repeated last digit. Let's call the estimate for the unconditional probability of a number with $m$ digits to be prime $p_m$ (more on that below); then we can write the sum of the probabilities for all $m$-digit numbers with repeated last digit as

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&
\frac{9}{8}p_m\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}9^k{\left(m-2 \atop k-1\right)} \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^kp_{m-1}^k
\\
&=&
\frac{9}{8}\frac{5}{2}9p_mp_{m-1}\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}9^k{\left(m-2 \atop k\right)} \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^kp_{m-1}^k
\\
&=&
\frac{405}{16}p_mp_{m-1}\left(1+\frac{45}{2}p_{m-1}\right)^{m-2}\;,
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where the orginal sum now only runs up to $m-1$ since the last digit cannot be repeated for $k=m$.

Now let's turn to the slightly more complicated case where the last digit isn't repeated. That reduces both the number of digits and the number of places at which to divide the repetitions, so there are $9^k\left(m-2 \atop k-2\right)$ such numbers. The sum works out as it should, since $\left(m-2 \atop k-1\right)+\left(m-2 \atop k-2\right)=\left(m-1 \atop k-1\right)$.

If the last digit doesn't repeat, we don't know whether deleting the last digit makes the number divisible by $2$ or $5$, and there is correlation between the events of the last deletion leaving the number coprime to $2$ and $5$ and the last two deletions leaving it coprime to $3$. Thus we need to determine the conditional probability that all three of these events occur given that the original number is prime.

Again, the last digit can be $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$. But now the penultimate digit also has to be one of these, since otherwise the deletion of the last digit would render the number divisible by $2$. Thus we have $16$ combinations for the last two digits, $4$ of which are excluded because the digits cannot be the same. We have two different cases to consider, depending on whether $1$ and $7$ (which have the same remainder mod $3$) are allowed or not. Each of these cases occurs with probability $1/2$, depending on whether the remainder of the original number mod $3$ is $1$ or $2$. (Strictly speaking, the probabilities for these two cases are also slightly correlated with the probabilities being determined, but I believe this correlation should decay quickly as $m$ increases.)

So with probability $1/2$, only $3$ and $9$ are allowed, so the only combinations for the last two digits are $39$ and $93$. In the other case, all $4$ digits, and hence all $12$ combinations, are allowed. Thus, on average $7$ combinations of the last two digits lead to the last two deletions leaving the number coprime to $2$, $3$ and $5$, out of the $4\cdot9=36$ that are possible given that the original number is prime. That yields a conditional probability $7/36$, which we need to divide by the unconditional probability $(\lvert\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}\rvert/30)^2=(4/15)^2$ of two numbers being coprime to $2$, $3$ and $5$ to get the factor $(7/36)(15/4)^2=175/64$ by which we need to multiply the unconditional probability. All remaining digits contribute a factor of $5/2$ because deleting them doesn't make the number divisible by $2$, and we don't need any correcting factors for the mod $3$ restrictions for the remaining digits, for the same reasons as above, so we're done. Putting it all together, we have for the sum of the probabilities for all $m$-digit numbers with non-repeated last digit:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&
\frac{175}{64}p_m\sum_{k=2}^{m}9^k{\left(m-2 \atop k-2\right)} \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{k-2}p_{m-1}^k
\\
&=&
9^2\frac{175}{64}p_mp_{m-1}^2\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}9^k{\left(m-2 \atop k\right)} \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^kp_{m-1}^k
\\
&=&
\frac{14175}{64}p_mp_{m-1}^2\left(1+\frac{45}{2}p_{m-1}\right)^{m-2}\;,
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where the original sum starts at $2$ since the last digit necessarily repeats for $k=1$.

The ratio between the two results is $(35/4)p_{m-1}\approx(35/4)/((m-1)\log 10)\approx 3.8/(m-1)$, so for small $m$ there are more numbers with the last digit not repeated and for large $m$ there are more with the last digit repeated, in agreement with the numerical data.

We can bound $p_m$ by $1/\log m$ from above as before, and then show as before that for both cases the sum over the probabilities for all $m$ converges. To get a better estimate, we can take $p_m$ to be the average density of primes for all $m$-digit numbers, which is

$$p_m=\frac{\frac{10^m}{\log10^m}-\frac{10^{m-1}}{\log10^{m-1}}}{10^m-10^{m-1}}=\frac{1}{9\log 10}\left(\frac{10}{m}-\frac{1}{m-1}\right)\;.$$

Here are plots of [the repeated case](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28405/16%20%2a%20%2810/m-1/%28m-1%29%29%2a%2810/%28m-1%29-1/%28m-2%29%29%2a%281%2b45%2a%2810/%28m-1%29-1/%28m-2%29%29/%282%2a9%2alog%2810%29%29%29%5E%28m-2%29/%289%2alog%2810%29%29%5E2%29%20from%20m%20=%203%20to%2040%20&incParTime=true), [the non-repeated case](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%2814175%2f64+%2a+%2810%2fm-1%2f%28m-1%29%29%2a%2810%2f%28m-1%29-1%2f%28m-2%29%29%2a%2810%2f%28m-1%29-1%2f%28m-2%29%29%2a%281%2b45%2a%2810%2f%28m-1%29-1%2f%28m-2%29%29%2f%282%2a9%2alog%2810%29%29%29%5e%28m-2%29%2f%289%2alog%2810%29%29%5e3%29+from+m+%3d+3+to+40+&incParTime=true) and [the total](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28%281%2b%2835/%2836%2alog%2810%29%29%29%2a%2810/%28m-1%29-1/%28m-2%29%29%29%2a405/16%20%2a%20%2810/m-1/%28m-1%29%29%2a%2810/%28m-1%29-1/%28m-2%29%29%2a%281%2b45%2a%2810/%28m-1%29-1/%28m-2%29%29/%282%2a9%2alog%2810%29%29%29%5E%28m-2%29/%289%2alog%2810%29%29%5E2%29%20from%20m%20=%203%20to%2040&incParTime=true). The maxima are at $m=18$, $7$ and $15$ with maximal values of and $21$, $8$ and $26$, respectively. The expected total counts (summed numerically) are $1794$, $209$ and $2003$, respectively. Thus, we can expect there to be around $2000$ of these numbers in total; about half of these have $74$ digits or more.

Here's a table comparing the actual counts for $3$ to $11$ digits (using the numerical data I report further down) to the above estimates:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
m&\text{last digit repeated}&\text{last digit not repeated}&\text{total}\\\hline\\
\begin{array}{c}
\mathrm{\vphantom{actual}\vphantom{estimate}}\\
\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
5\\
6\\
7\\
8\\
9\\
10\\
11\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm{actual}&\mathrm{estimate}\\
\hline\\
0&\\
1&4\\
3&6\\
7&8\\
12&11\\
5&13\\
8&15\\
11&16\\
21&17\\
16&19\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm{actual}&\mathrm{estimate}\\
\hline\\
4&\\
10&6\\
11&7\\
9&8\\
6&8\\
8&8\\
6&8\\
7&8\\
1&7\\
7&7\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm{actual}&\mathrm{estimate}\\
\hline\\
4&\\
11&10\\
14&13\\
16&16\\
18&19\\
13&21\\
14&22\\
18&24\\
22&25\\
23&25\\
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

The agreement turns out to be quite good, though there seems to be a slight overestimation now. I have no explanation for this, since the only systematic effect I can think of that I haven't taken into account is the correlation between the size of the original number and the size of the modified numbers, which should increase rather than decrease the probabilities. (In case you're wondering whether this is a case of changing the theory until it fits the data, it was actually the other way around: I got several incorrect results for the non-repeated case that would have removed the overestimation, but I believe the above analysis is the correct one.)

Here are all the numbers with up to $11$ digits (up to the 4,239,555,920th prime); I checked that they coincide with the ones already reported, but I'm putting them all here to have them together in one place:

23,
37,
53,
73,
113,
131,
137,
173,
179,
197,
311,
317,
431,
617,
719,
1013,
1031,
1097,
1499,
1997,
2239,
2293,
3137,
4019,
4919,
6173,
7019,
7433,
9677,
10193,
10613,
11093,
19973,
23833,
26833,
30011,
37019,
40013,
47933,
73331,
74177,
90011,
91733,
93491,
94397,
111731,
166931,
333911,
355933,
477797,
477977,
633317,
633377,
665293,
700199,
719333,
746099,
779699,
901499,
901997,
944777,
962233,
991733,
1367777,
1440731,
1799999,
2668999,
3304331,
3716633,
4437011,
5600239,
6666437,
6913337,
7333331,
7364471,
7391117,
13334117,
22255999,
33771191,
38800999,
40011197,
40097777,
44333339,
49473377,
79994177,
86000899,
93361493,
94400477,
99396617,
99917711,
110499911,
144170699,
199033997,
222559399,
333904433,
461133713,
469946111,
640774499,
679774391,
680006893,
711110111,
716664317,
743444477,
889309999,
900117773,
982669999,
999371099,
999444431,
1113399311,
1133333777,
1176991733,
1466664677,
1667144477,
1716336911,
2350000999,
3336133337,
3355522333,
3443339111,
3973337999,
4111116011,
4900001111,
6446999477,
6666116411,
6689899999,
6914333711,
7463333477,
8555555599,
8888333599,
8936093833,
9746666477,
10000000097,
10666610333,
11100077711,
11793334733,
19000019333,
23525555899,
30001114937,
33008299999,
33110666399,
33399911777,
37796941199,
40470660977,
44434133339,
46661333333,
46666133333,
55888856893,
61077333377,
66664441373,
66700447613,
66993413393,
71111164499,
77443733111,
99444901133

Some interesting specimens are 10000000097 (which is the only one with lots of $0$s after the first digit, showing that there's no significant effect from the overestimation of the size of the modified numbers in such a case) and the pair 46661333333 and 46666133333.

Here's the Java program I used to find these (using a bit set as Fixee suggested to cram as many primes as possible into my 8GB). The computation took half an hour on a MacBook Pro i7.

```
public class EdiblePrimes {
    static class LongBitSet {
        int [] bits;

        public LongBitSet (long nbits) {
            bits = new int [(int) ((nbits + 0x1f) >> 5)];
        }

        public void clear (long bit) {
            bits [index (bit)] &= ~mask (bit);
        }
        public void set (long bit) {
            bits [index (bit)] |= mask (bit);
        }
        public boolean get (long bit) {
            return (bits [index (bit)] & mask (bit)) != 0;
        }
        private static int mask (long bit) {
            return 1 << (bit & 0x1f);
        }
        private static int index (long bit) {
            return (int) (bit >> 5);
        }
    }

    final static long max = 0x1800000000L;
    final static long maxIndex = max >> 1;

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        LongBitSet composite = new LongBitSet (maxIndex); // bit at index n says whether 2n+1 is composite 
        composite.set (0); // 1 isn't prime

        int maxDivisor = (int) (Math.sqrt (max) + 1);

        for (int divisor = 3;divisor < maxDivisor;divisor += 2)
            if (!composite.get (divisor >> 1))
                for (long multiple = (3 * divisor) >> 1;multiple < maxIndex;multiple += divisor)
                    composite.set (multiple);

    outer:
        for (long n = 11;n < max;n += 2) {
            if (!composite.get (n >> 1)) {
                long power = 1;
                do {
                    long nextPower = 10 * power;
                    long modified = n % power + (n / nextPower) * power;
                    if (modified != 2 && ((modified & 1) == 0 || composite.get (modified >> 1)))
                        continue outer;
                    power = nextPower;
                } while (power < n);
                System.out.println (n);
            }
    }
}
```

[**Update**:]

Since the probability has a simple $k$ dependence, we can calculate the expectation value for $k$, i.e. the expected number of strings of repeated digits. For the shifted sums over $k$, we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&
\frac{
\sum\left(m-2 \atop k\right) k q^k
}{
\sum\left(m-2 \atop k\right) q^k
}
\\
&=&
\frac{
q\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\sum\left(m-2 \atop k\right)q^k
}{
\sum\left(m-2 \atop k\right) q^k
}
\\
&=&
\frac{
q\frac{\partial}{\partial q}(1+q)^{m-2}
}{
(1+q)^{m-2}
}
\\
&=&
\frac{
(m-2)q(1+q)^{m-3}
}{
(1+q)^{m-2}
}
\\
&=&
\frac{m-2}{1+q^{-1}}\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

With $q\approx 45/(2(m-1)\log10)$, this becomes

$$
\frac{m-2}{1+\frac{2(m-1)\log10}{45}}\to_{m\to\infty}\frac{45}{2\log{10}}\approx 10\;.
$$

We shifted $k$ down by $1$ and $2$ for numbers with with last digit repeated and not repeated, respectively. Thus, if we don't count a non-repeated last digit as a separate string, we get the same expectation value in both cases, namely $1$ more than the above value. Thus, in the limit of large $n$, there will be about $11$ strings of repeated digits on average (not counting non-repeated last digits), but the values for small $m$ are not near the limit because of the large factor of $45$. Here's a comparison of the actual averages with the estimated expectation values (using the above better estimate for $p_m$):

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\\
m&\text{actual}&\text{estimated}\\
\hline\\
2&1.0&\\
3&1.9&1.8\\
4&2.8&2.5\\
5&3.5&3.1\\
6&3.8&3.6\\
7&4.1&4.1\\
8&4.4&4.5\\
9&5.3&4.8\\
10&5.4&5.1\\
11&5.7&5.4
\end{array}
$$

Here, too, the agreement is quite good, but there seems to be a slight systematic error left.

Comment: It's quite a good answer.  But I don't buy the part about the marginal density: 1/log x is a better estimate than 1/log x - 1/log^2 x since you want to approximate Li'(x) rather than (x/log x)'.

Answer (score 20):

I wrote an application in Java that searches the numbers. Here are the results in the range [1,100.000] (the original number isn't necessarily a prime itself)

22
23
25
27
32
33
35
37
52
53
55
57
72
73
75
77
111
113
117
119
131
137
171
173
179
197
311
317
371
411
413
417
431
437
471
473
611
617
671
711
713
719
731
1013
1031
1037
1073
1079
1097
1379
1397
1499
1673
1739
1937
1991
1997
2233
2239
2277
2293
2571
2577
2811
3113
3131
3137
3173
3311
3317
3479
4019
4199
4331
4433
4439
4499
4631
4919
4991
5577
5877
6017
6173
6431
6773
7019
7433
7619
7733
8211
8239
8277
8577
8811
8877
9191
9677
9911
9971
9977
10193
10613
10619
11093
11871
12777
14871
14933
14993
14999
16637
16997
17877
19733
19973
23833
24111
26833
27411
30011
31637
34691
36917
37019
40013
40073
40919
42111
47933
47993
49337
49733
52333
60911
61733
61997
63011
71877
73331
74177
74517
74817
74877
75417
75477
81117
81171
82693
90011
90491
91733
93491
94133
94337
94391
94397
94733
97433

---

If the extra condition is that the original number has to be a prime, there are other results (range [1,100.000.000]:

23
37
53
73
113
131
137
173
179
197
311
317
431
617
719
1013
1031
1097
1499
1997
2239
2293
3137
4019
4919
6173
7019
7433
9677
10193
10613
11093
19973
23833
26833
30011
37019
40013
47933
73331
74177
90011
91733
93491
94397
111731
166931
333911
355933
477797
477977
633317
633377
665293
700199
719333
746099
779699
901499
901997
944777
962233
991733
1367777
1440731
1799999
2668999
3304331
3716633
4437011
5600239
6666437
6913337
7333331
7364471
7391117
13334117
22255999
33771191
38800999
40011197
40097777
44333339
49473377
79994177
86000899
93361493
94400477
99396617
99917711

---

The source code of the application is this:

```
/**
 *
 * @author martijn
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        outer:
        for (int i = 11; i < 100000; ++i) {

            /* If the condition is that the original has to be a prime,
             * uncomment following three lines */
        //    if (!isPrime(i)) {
        //        continue;
        //    }

            String str = String.valueOf(i);
            int len = str.length();
            for (int c = 0; c < len; ++c)
            {
                int ci = len - c - 1;
                int s = (i / pow10(ci + 1) * pow10(ci)) + (i % pow10(ci));
                if (!isPrime(s))
                {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    }

    public static int pow10(int pow)
    {
        switch(pow)
        {
            case 0: return 1;
            case 1: return 10;
            case 2: return 100;
            case 3: return 1000;
            case 4: return 10000;
            case 5: return 100000;
            case 6: return 1000000;
            case 7: return 10000000;
            case 8: return 100000000;
            case 9: return 1000000000;
        }
        // You are searching VERY high numbers
        return -1;
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int g) {
        if (g < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        if (g == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((g & 1) == 0) // If even
        {
            return false;
        }
        // A few cheap checks
        if (g <= 113) {
            if (g == 3) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 5) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 7) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 11) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 13) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 17) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 19) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 23) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 29) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 31) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 37) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 41) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 43) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 47) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 53) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 59) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 61) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 67) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 71) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 73) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 79) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 83) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 89) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 97) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 101) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 103) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 107) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 109) {
                return true;
            }
            if (g == 113) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        int max = (int) Math.ceil((Math.sqrt((double) g)));
        for (int i = 3; i <= max; i += 2) {
            if (g % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you could heavily optimize that Java code. Add a `static ArrayList<Integer> primes` and a `static int max`; then, `isPrime(int g)` should start with `if (max >= g && !primes.contains(g)){return false;} max = g;` and invoke `primes.add(g);` before `return true`. Take a look at [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) for more info. Also you could rewrite that `if` tree as `if (g <= 113) { switch(g) { case 3: case 5: case 7: /* etc */ case 113: return true; default: return false; } }` for readability's sake.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You are right. That was about 3 years ago. I guess I wasn't really that good at optimization yet. I was 15 back then :)

Answer (score 16):

Using the link provided by @joriki in the comments, I found Mathematica code to find such primes (I am using the code that allows 0s as you can then get all those that do not allow 0 simply by deleting the primes with 0s).

```
rpQ[n_] := Module[{idn = IntegerDigits[n]}, And @@ 
           PrimeQ[FromDigits /@ Subsets[idn, {Length[idn] - 1}]]];
```

Here is the list of all such numbers from the first 436 million primes.

23, 37, 53, 73, 113, 131, 137, 173, 179, 197, 311, 317, 431, 617, 719, 1013, 1031, 1097, 1499, 1997, 2239, 2293, 3137, 4019, 4919, 6173, 7019, 7433, 9677, 10193, 10613, 11093, 19973, 23833, 26833, 30011, 37019, 40013, 47933, 73331, 74177, 90011, 91733, 93491, 94397, 111731, 166931, 333911, 355933, 477797, 477977, 633317, 633377, 665293, 700199, 719333, 746099, 779699, 901499, 901997, 944777, 962233, 991733, 1367777, 1440731, 1799999, 2668999, 3304331, 3716633, 4437011, 5600239, 6666437, 6913337, 7333331, 7364471, 7391117, 13334117, 22255999, 33771191, 38800999, 40011197, 40097777, 44333339, 49473377, 79994177, 86000899, 93361493, 94400477, 99396617, 99917711, 110499911, 144170699, 199033997, 222559399, 333904433, 461133713, 469946111, 640774499, 679774391, 680006893, 711110111, 716664317, 743444477, 889309999, 900117773, 982669999, 999371099, 999444431, 1113399311, 1133333777, 1176991733, 1466664677, 1667144477, 1716336911, 2350000999, 3336133337, 3355522333, 3443339111, 3973337999, 4111116011, 4900001111, 6446999477, 6666116411, 6689899999, 6914333711, 7463333477, 8555555599, 8888333599, 8936093833

There are some things we can say about such numbers.

1. The last 2 digits can only ever consist 1, 3, 7, or 9 since any number ending in 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8 is composite (other than single digit numbers).
2. The sum of the digits can not be 0 mod 3, because the number would be divisible by 3.  And, if the sum of the digits is 1 mod 3, then none of the digits of the number can be 1 mod 3.  Similarly, if the sum of the digits is 2 mod 3 then, then none of the digits can be 2 mod 3.  So, every such number is comprised of at most 0, 3, 6, 9, and 1, 4, 7 OR 0, 3, 6, 9, and 2, 5, 8.
3. These should be much more rare if you generalize to more than 1 delete.  If there were 2 deletes, the mod 3 argument would rule out most cases.  I believe the only case possible would be the digits add to 1 mod 3 and all the digits are 1 mod 3, or the digits add to 2 mod 3 and all the digits are 2 mod 3.  So, they could only contain 1, 4, and 7 OR 2, 5, 8.  In the second case, ending with any of those numbers makes the original not prime.  So, we only have the first case.  They must have the digits 1, 4, 7 only.  And, they would have to contain 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, ... digits to ensure the digit totals worked out.

Answer (score 9):

Here's my C code for generating these numbers.  It should be very fast since it uses a sieve, but also consumes a lot of memory for the sieve[] array (we could compress by a factor of 8 by using a bitfield).

```
// find primes such that deleting any digit remains a prime
//
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000000000LL
char sieve[MAX];

int ddel(long long i);
int main(void) {
  long long i, j;

  sieve[0] = sieve[1] = 0;  // don't count 0 and 1 as primes
  for (i=2; i < MAX; i++) sieve[i] = 1;

  // sieve; each new prime will be tested
  for (i=2; i < MAX; i++) {
    if (sieve[i] == 0) continue;
    for (j=i+i; j < MAX; j += i) sieve[j] = 0;

    if (i > 10) {
      if (ddel(i))
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
  }
}

int ddel(long long i) {
  long long j;
  long long t = 1;

  while (t < i) {
    // delete the log_10(t) digit
    j = i/10/t * t + i%t;
    if (sieve[j] == 0) return 0;
    t *= 10;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the relaxation that the original number need not be prime (treated in an answer) digit repetitions give large solutions.

Playing with 2 decimal digits gave the $332$ digit composite solution

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Comment: Note that my estimate predicts $0.64$ solutions with repeated last digit with $332$ digits even if the original number is prime. Dropping the condition that the original number is prime removes a factor $p_m$ and increases the expected number of solutions to $489$. For most of these the number of strings of repeated digits is around the average value of $10$; the expected number of solutions with $332$ digits, repeated last digit and only $2$ strings of repeated digits is about $0.32$.

Comment: @joriki OK. I suppose it is hard to find large solutions because of the large number of possibilities. I couldn't find a prime solution of only 2 digits up 380 (and with 3 digits I couldn't find large composite solution).

Comment: That's not surprising if you look at my estimates. Solutions with few digits are rare; most of the solutions have around $10$ strings of repeated digits.