# Is it ever $i$ time?

Tags: soft-question, complex-numbers

I am asking this question as a response to reading two different questions:

[Is it ever Pi time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63198/is-it-ever-really-pi-time)
and 
[Are complex number real?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154/do-complex-numbers-really-exist%5C)

So I ask, is it ever $i$ time?  Could we arbitrarily define  time as following the imaginary line instead of the real one?

(NOTE:  I have NO experience with complex numbers, so I apologize if this is a truly dumb question.  It just followed from my reading, and I want to test my understanding)

Comment: If you take the Argand viewpoint, you're then asking if "time" can have more than one dimension... if it does have two dimensions, then there's a way to interpret $i$...

Comment: "following a complex line" - it's a "real line", but a "complex plane"... ;)

Comment: If you think of the complex plane, at 12:00 both hands point to $i$.

Comment: @J.M -- I thought that complex numbers formed a plane, but that imaginary numbers were on a line (and the plane came from combining the imaginary with the real)... Oh, maybe I should have said "imaginary line?"

Comment: If time were imaginary some things would get weird. For example, if you accelerate at $50 \frac{mi}{hr^2}$ and the hours were imaginary numbers, then the $hr^2$ would end up flipping the sign of your acceleration. We know this doesn't happen physically, so imaginary time in this sense won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes; if you'll refer to the Wikipedia page on [Imaginary Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_time), you'll see that imaginary time is a useful concept in quantum mechanics.

EDIT: As an aside, your question is very far from dumb. The desire to generalize anything and everything to complex numbers (and, for the number theorists out there, to $p$-adic numbers) has shown, historically, to be a natural and very fruitful instinct.

Answer (score 0):

In the Wikipedia article titled [Paul Émile Appell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_%C3%89mile_Appell), we read that "He discovered a physical interpretation of the imaginary period of the doubly periodic function whose restriction to real arguments describes the motion of an ideal pendulum."

The interpretation is this: The real period is the real period.  The maximum deviation from vertical is $\theta$.  The imaginary period is what the period would be if that maximum deviation were $\pi - \theta$.