# Nonlinear differential equation: $-y'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha y(t)^2+y(t)^{3/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In a paper the differential equation $-y'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha y(t)^2+y(t)^{3/2}$ occured. First of all, it does not satisfy the usual Lipschitz-condition. But there are probably weaker criteria. The solution was given as:
$$
y(t)=\frac{4}{\alpha^2}\left(1+W(-C_1 e^{-\frac{t}{\alpha}})\right)^{-2},
$$
where $W$ is the Lamber-$W$-function. Mathemica/WolframAlpha give nothing. I have not yet seen such a differential equation. How can one solve this?

Comment: Maple, though, finds an implicit solution. Plus, this is just a separable equation, which should be straightforward to solve.

Comment: It's usually a good idea when referring to Wolfram|Alpha results to link to them. In the present case, it seems you entered the equation either incorrectly or in an inconvenient form; when I enter it, I get [an implicit solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+-y%27%3Da+y^2+%2F+2+%2B+y^%283%2F2%29).

Comment: Ouch, that is actually easy to see. I was so puzzled by this $W$-function. However, this was my input: [WA-Input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5By%27%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+1%2F2*a*y%5Bx%5D%5E2%2B%28y%5Bx%5D%29%5E%283%2F2%29%2C+y%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D). To my knowledge, this is standard mathematica input.

Comment: The right side of the equation is locally Lipschitz (on $[0,\infty)$).  To avoid problems with negative $y$, replace the $y^{3/2}$ on the right side with $|y^{3/2}|$.  Since this modified equation satisfies the hypotheses of the existence and uniqueness theorem, and $y=0$ is a solution, the solution with any initial value $> 0$ will never hit $0$, so you don't have to worry about negative $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to solve such a [separable first-order ordinary differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_differential_equations#Separable_first-order_ordinary_differential_equations) is to divide through by the function of $y$ to get separate integrals with respect to $t$ and $y$:

$$
-\frac{y'}{\frac12\alpha y^2+y^{3/2}}=1\;,
\\
\int-\frac{y'}{\frac12\alpha y^2+y^{3/2}}\mathrm dx=\int1\,\mathrm dt\;,
\\
\int-\frac1{\frac12\alpha y^2+y^{3/2}}\mathrm dy=\int1\,\mathrm dt\;.
$$

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201/%28a%20y%5E2%20/%202%20%2b%20y%5E%283/2%29%29) solves the integral on the left (and shows steps if you click "Show Steps"):

$$\frac2{\sqrt y}-\alpha\log\left(\alpha+\frac2{\sqrt y}\right)=t+C\;.$$

With $u=\alpha+2/\sqrt y$, this becomes

$$u-\alpha\log u=t+C'\;.$$

Rescaling by $u=-\alpha s$ to get rid of the factor $-\alpha$, we get

$$s+\log s=-\frac t\alpha+C''\;.$$

Then exponentiating yields

$$s\mathrm e^s=C'''\mathrm e^{-t/\alpha}\;,$$

which is solved using the Lambert W function by

$$s=W\left(C'''\mathrm e^{-t/\alpha}\right)\;.$$

Then resolving the substitutions yields

$$y=\left(\frac2{u-\alpha}\right)^2=\left(\frac2\alpha\right)^2\left(1+s\right)^{-2}=\frac4{\alpha^2}\left(1+W\left(C'''\mathrm e^{-t/\alpha}\right)\right)^{-2}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer!

Comment: @user13655: You're welcome!

Comment: @user13655 I think joriki has other standards for [extensive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33094/deleting-any-digit-yields-a-prime-is-there-a-name-for-this/33303#33303)