# Prime number where all (ordered) combinations of digits are prime

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Are there any prime numbers with more than two digits such that all combinations of its digits (preserving order) are prime? For example, if the number `abc` is prime, then `a`, `b`, and `c` are prime, and so are `ab`, `ac`, and `bc`.

What is the largest such number, or the largest known? I'm not even sure this is possible, but I imagine the probability of a prime passing this test gets really small really fast as you start adding digits...

Comment: @joriki 33 is not prime.

Comment: @John: oops :-)

Comment: I plan on making a script to check, I just though someone else might have fun with this question too. I wonder if you can prove something general about this...

Comment: For 3 digits, there are none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such number. All digits except the first would have to be $3$, $7$ or $9$, since $1$ is not a prime and the remaining digits cannot be the last digits of primes with more than one digit. It cannot contain the same digit twice, since that would yield a number divisible by $11$. It also can't contain $39$ or $93$, which are divisible by $3$. That leaves only $37$, $73$, $97$ and $79$, preceded by one prime digit other than $3$ or $7$, i.e. $2$ or $5$. None of the eight resulting numbers is prime.

Comment: That's a much better way to check than what I was going to do! Thanks!

Comment: 9 is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

Largest is 73.

A related sequence is [A051362](http://oeis.org/A051362), where all combinations of removing a single digit gives a prime number.  That's a finite list, so it's a simple matter of looking there.

Comment: a) The question asked for numbers with more than two digits, so $73$ isn't one. b) The fact that that OEIS list is finite doesn't mean that there are finitely many such numbers. The entry itself says that the linked list of $200$ numbers only goes up to $10^{13}$. In response to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33094) I estimated that we should expect there to be about $2000$ such numbers, of which roughly half should be expected to have $74$ digits or more.